# How to use feature selection with predict proba in sklearn in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, cross-validation

I am currently using the following code to get the prediction probability (i.e. `predict_proba` in `sklearn`) of each each data point using `cross validation`.

```
df = pd.read_csv(input_file)
X = df[features]
y = df[["gold_standard"]]

clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, random_state = 42, class_weight="balanced")
k_fold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
proba = cross_val_predict(clf, X, y, cv=k_fold, method="predict_proba")
```

---

However, now I want to *first* use feature selection (e.g., [`RFECV` (Recursive Feature Elimination with Cross Validation)](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html)) to filter my features, and *then* get the prediction probability (i.e. `predict_proba`) of each data point in `cross validation`.

```
rfecv = RFECV(estimator=clf, step=1, cv=k_fold)
```

However, I am confused how to do the `predict proba` part, since now I cannot use `cross_val_predict` with `rfecv`. Is it correct to straightaway say (does that do the same functionality of my first code?);

```
rfecv.predict_proba(X,y)
```

Please let me know a suitable way of doing this in `sklearn`.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: You don't want to use `cross_val_predict` in `RFECV`, you want a scorer to do the feature elimination, and then do the predict

Comment: @ItamarMushkin It would be greatly appreciated if you could tell me how to do this in code. Looking forward to hearing from you :)